# Как правильно написать запрос SQL, на выборку из нескольких таблиц?

Tags: mysql, sql, выборка

Выбираю вот так:
1. `SELECT x.id, y.id, z.id, w.id, s.id FROM x, z, y, w, s ORDER BY x.id DESC, y.id DESC, z.id DESC, w.id DESC, s.id DESC limit 1`
2. или через `SELECT MAX(x.id) ...`

Проблема в том что выборка без `DESC`, занимает 0.001 сек, а вот с `DESC` первый вариант 35сек, а второй 15 сек...

И вот тут я подумал, что нужна помощь. Смотрел в сторону `JOIN`, но не понял как его сюда присобачить. Мне не нужно сравнивать ничего, просто достать последние записи с каждой из таблиц.

Comment: Есть ли индексы по полям, которые вы объединяете в where? А DESC  - конечно будет "подтормаживать", т.к. скан таблиц идет

Comment: есть index по полям ид. И здесь нет where, поэтому может и тормозит, ибо нет ключа поиска, и критерия поиска... Потому что, как задать критерий поиска по иду в where, если мне нужно выбрать без критерия, просто последние записи ? WHERE max(id) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Chubatiy спасибо, подтолкнул к мысли.

Возможно это из разряда извращений, но как вариант должен существовать.

```
SELECT x.id, y.id 
FROM x, y
WHERE x.id=( SELECT max(id) FROM x ), 
      y.id=( SELECT max(id) FROM y) LIMIT 1
```

Такой вариант, через подзапросы выполнился за 0.0028 (только у меня 8 таблиц, с 5 полями в каждой)

Comment: может тогда уж select (select max(a.id) from a), (select max(b.d) from b) ... И общего from с перечислением всех таблиц не надо т.к. именно он тормозит пытаясь перемножить сожержимое

Comment: попробовал такой вариант, но он катит только если   
`SELECT (SELECT MAX(b.id) FROM b)` = одна колонка во внутреннем селекте, если для одной таблицы писать в таком стиле несколько колонок, то запрос будет километровый . Если несколько бьет ошибку #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) - то есть разрешена только одна колонка. Хотя выполняется на порядок быстрее, 0.0010

Comment: Да, есть такое дело. тогда `select * from (select max(id) a,min(id) b from b) A, (select ... from b) B ...` главное что бы все запросы возвращали ровно по одной строке.

Comment: а вы что-то еще кроме x.id, y.id выбираете? потому что если нет - то и смысла в такой выборке нет - гораздо проще взять `SELECT MAX(x.id), MAX(y.id) FROM x, y`

Comment: @PashaPash так в изначальном вопросе ТС так и было. только в таком случае оптимизатор сделает полный скан обоих таблиц, перемножит результаты и только после этого из результата выберет максимальные значения